# How to refresh System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles().Length

Tags: c#, directoryinfo, getfiles

I'm having trouble with getting the uptodate amount of files in a directory. The files are being printed from PDFCreator and being sent to that folder. When the number of files in the folder match the number of files being printed it should then break and continue with my code. The problem is the count doesn't keep uptodate and I do not know how to refresh it. This is my code:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo pdf = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\0TeklaBatchProcess\pdf");
int count = pdf.GetFiles().Length;

while (count != DE.GetSize())
{
    if (count < DE.GetSize())
    {
        pdf.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If someone can tell me how to refresh or update the count of files I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count` is a local `int` - the only way to update that would be to query it again. Try replacing `pdf.Refresh()` with:

```
count = pdf.GetFiles().Length;
```

(actually, `Directory.GetFiles(di.FullName).Length` is probably cheaper)

However! You **don't** want to do this in a tight loop; maybe add a `Sleep(1000)`, or (better) use `FileSystemWatcher`. Even better still; check for a *specific* file so you don't hit `GetFiles()` aggressively.

Comment: count = pdf.GetFiles().Length worked. Thanks so much for that, can't believe I didn't try it. I had tried Sleep but it didn't work because the count still hadn't updated. I can't check for a specific file because the names of the files are different all the time. Even though it's working now I'm interested in how to use FileSystemWatcher to check the amount of files since you said it was better. Can you show me how?

Comment: @Mutley - sorry, that isn't something I've done except for a few test projects

Comment: ok, no problem. Thanks again! I'd vote up on your answer but don't have enough rep..